# How to store files in local storage using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, file, local-storage

I would like to store uploaded files locally(local-storage) using jquery can anyone help me

```
<input name="file" type="file" />
    <input type="button" value="Store" />
</form>
```

Comment: This is a good jQuery tool for upload http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/. This is a good tool for download - http://jquery.com/download/

Comment: Wut? "Store uploaded files locally"? So are these files uploaded (remote) or local? Anyway, localStorage can accept only strings, not files or anything else. And no need for jQuery at all. Use `localStorage.someKey = "some val"`.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE**

You cant upload and store files using localstorage.

If you want to use local storage,you dnt need a jquery. HTML5 provides you with that feature.

```
localStorage.setItem('userid','2'); //To set a data

var userId = localStorage.getItem('userid'); // To get a data

localStorage.removeItem('userid'); //To remove a data
```

Refer this link for more details
[Local Storage](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/11/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/)

Comment: This is correct answer but I would recommend usage of Store.js wrapper (https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js/) to ensure browser compatibility.  It uses localStorage, globalStorage, and userData behavior under the hood.

Comment: Learnt something new...dint know about that. Thanx for the info